# How do I add extra information to XML generated from a dataset Writexml in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

```
ds.WriteXml(strXmlTestCasePath, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

ds is a `dataset`. I want to add an extra line or extra information into this XML.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply write more XML to the end of a serialized `DataSet`, since if you do you'll be producing an XML document with more than one top-level element.  Using an `XmlWriter`, you'd need to do something like this:

```
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(strXmlTestCasePath));
{
   xw.WriteStartElement("container");
   ds.WriteXml(xw, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
   // from here on, you can use the XmlWriter to add XML to the end; you then
   // have to wrap things up by closing the enclosing "container" element:
   ...
   xw.WriteEndElement();
}
```

But this won't help you if what you're trying to do is add XML elements *inside* the serialized `DataSet`.  To do that, you'll need to serialize the `DataSet`, read it into an `XmlDocument`, and then use DOM methods to manipulate the XML.

Or, alternatively, create and populate a new `DataTable` right before you serialize the `DataSet` and then delete it when you're done.  It really depends on what your actual requirements are.

Answer (score 5):

Use an `XmlWriter` to write your `DataSet`. You can then use the same object to write additional XML.

illustrative code:

```
            System.Data.DataSet ds;
            System.Xml.XmlWriter x;
            ds.WriteXml(x);
            x.WriteElementString("test", "value");
```

Comment: i want it to write it to same xml

Comment: It is a reference to the same object you use to write your DataSet's xml and extra xml to.

Comment: actually my question is i have  saved my dataset in a xml now after writing it to the xml i have to add a extra line inside the xml which i saved now

Comment: Yes, and he answered your question.  What part of his answer do you think doesn't answer your question?

Comment: when run this code its returns error as use of unassigned  local variables

Comment: My code snippet was just to illustrate the use of an xmlwriter together with a DataSet, of course is doesn't work.